# Angular navigation for sub components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Router-Outlet to display different components selected by user

```html
<nav>
  <a id="home" routerLink="/home" >Home</a>
  <a id="about" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
  <a id="open-close" routerLink="/open-close" routerLinkActive="active">Open/Close</a>
  <a id="status" routerLink="/status" routerLinkActive="active">Status Slider</a>
  <a id="toggle" routerLink="/toggle" routerLinkActive="active">Toggle Animations</a>
  <a id="enter-leave" routerLink="/enter-leave" routerLinkActive="active">Enter/Leave</a>
  <a id="auto" routerLink="/auto" routerLinkActive="active">Auto Calculation</a>
  <a id="heroes" routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Filter/Stagger</a>
  <a id="hero-groups" routerLink="/hero-groups" routerLinkActive="active">Hero Groups</a>
   <a id="My-App" routerLink="/My-App" routerLinkActive="active">My App</a>
</nav>

<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)" >
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Here's the "My-App" tab

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  Patients
</div>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let patient of patients" >
        <a > {{patient.name}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Now, whenever user clicks or selects any patient, I want to navigate to a new component called "Child-Component" and want to display the patient's full details.

What's the best way to achieve with/without using the top level "Router-Outlet"

Answer (score 1):

I guess your requirement to show the navigation and update some part of the page with child routes.

```
_______________________________
Nav           Nav           Nav
_______________________________


      Full Details

_______________________________
```

In the app.compoent.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
[
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                component: HomeComponent
                pathMatch: 'full',
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                loadChildren: './about/about.module#AboutModule',
                pathMatch: 'full',
            }
        ],
    },
]);
```

`about` route I have shown to use lazy-loaded module, which is the best way for loading parts of the application only when needed.

Long time back I had created a working angular project for testing these option, you can check this project for reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-loading-and-router-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers%2Fcustomers-routing.module.ts

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. From you example, when I click the Test One or Test Two, I want to load the new component in the RouterOutlet of app.component.html instead of creating new RouterOutlet in the customer list component, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just remove the inner `router-outlet`